# Easiest way to extract the urls from an html page using sed or awk only

Tags: html, regex, bash, sed, awk

I want to extract the URL from within the anchor tags of an html file.
This needs to be done in BASH using SED/AWK. No perl please.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Read this and be enlightened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: If you don't mind that: *There is no guarantee that you find all urls.* **or** *There is no guarantee that all urls you find are valid.* use one of the examples below.  If you do mind use an appropriate tool for the job (perl, python, ruby)

Comment: My previous comment is of course for any *easy* solution you might try. awk is powerful enough to do the job, heck you could theoretically implement perl in awk...

Comment: Is this like one of those survivor challenges, where you have to live for three days eating only termites? If not, seriously, why the restriction? Every modern system can install at least Perl, and from there, you have the whole web

Answer (score 66):

You could also do something like this (provided you have lynx installed)...

Lynx versions < 2.8.8

```
lynx -dump -listonly my.html
```

Lynx versions >= 2.8.8 (courtesy of @condit)

```
lynx -dump -hiddenlinks=listonly my.html
```

Comment: In Lynx 2.8.8 this has become `lynx -dump -hiddenlinks=listonly my.html`

Comment: Better `lynx dump -listonly -hiddenlinks=listonly my.html`; if you don't still have the bare `-listonly` you get body text, not just links.

Answer (score 46):

You asked for it:

```
$ wget -O - http://stackoverflow.com | \
  grep -io '<a href=['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*['"'"'"]' | \
  sed -e 's/^<a href=["'"'"']//i' -e 's/["'"'"']$//i'
```

This is a crude tool, so all the usual warnings about attempting to parse HTML with regular expressions apply.

Comment: Almost perfect, but what about this two cases:
1. You are matching only the ones that start with <a href
<a title="Title" href="sample">Match me</a>

2. What if there's two anchors in the same line

I made this modifications to the original solution:
`code`
cat index.html | grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | sed -e 's/<a/\n<a/g' | sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d'
`code`

Comment: thanks, works on Mac compared to many other solutions mentioned above

Answer (score 18):

```
grep "<a href=" sourcepage.html
  |sed "s/<a href/\\n<a href/g" 
  |sed 's/\"/\"><\/a>\n/2'
  |grep href
  |sort |uniq
```

1. The first grep looks for lines containing urls. You can add more elements
   after if you want to look only on local pages, so no http, but
   relative path.
2. The first sed will add a newline in front of each *a href* url tag with the \n
3. The second sed will shorten each url after the 2nd " in the line by replacing it with the */a* tag with a newline
   Both seds will give you each url on a single line, but there is garbage, so
4. The 2nd grep href cleans the mess up
5. The sort and uniq will give you one instance of each existing url present in the sourcepage.html

Comment: Nice break down of what each step should do.

Answer (score 16):

With the [Xidel - HTML/XML data extraction tool](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html), this can be done via:

```
$ xidel --extract "//a/@href" http://example.com/
```

With conversion to absolute URLs:

```
$ xidel --extract "//a/resolve-uri(@href, base-uri())" http://example.com/
```

Comment: concat expects 2 arguments but here only one (base url is given).

err:XPST0017: unknown function: concat #1
Did you mean: 
  In module http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions:
    concat #2-65535

Comment: @smihael: You're right, that's superfluous here. Removed it. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 15):

I made a few changes to Greg Bacon Solution

```
cat index.html | grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' | sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d'
```

This fixes two problems:

1. We are matching cases where the anchor doesn't start with href as first attribute
2. We are covering the possibility of having several anchors in the same line

Comment: But at least it solves the problem, none of the other solutions does

Comment: The best option here if you don't want to use Lynx and your anchors don't start with <a href...

Answer (score 12):

An example, since you didn't provide any sample

```
awk 'BEGIN{
RS="</a>"
IGNORECASE=1
}
{
  for(o=1;o<=NF;o++){
    if ( $o ~ /href/){
      gsub(/.*href=\042/,"",$o)
      gsub(/\042.*/,"",$o)
      print $(o)
    }
  }
}' index.html
```

Comment: Does this work for '<a href="http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/" target="_blank">SELFHTML aktuell</a>'

Comment: if i say it works, (maybe not 100%, but 99.99%) of the time, would you believe?? :). The best is to try out yourself on various pages and see.

Comment: this really did the work, many great thanx for this great awk bundle!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it quite easily with the following regex, which is quite good at finding URLs:

```
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))
```

I took it from [John Gruber's article on how to find URLs in text](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls).

That lets you find all URLs in a file f.html as follows:

```
cat f.html | grep -o \
    -E '\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))'
```

Comment: complicated, and fails when href is like this: ... HREF="http://www.somewhere.com/" ADD_DATE="1197958879" LAST_MODIFIED="1249591429"> ...

Comment: I tried it on the daringfireball page itself and it found all links. other solutions may fail because href= could be somewhere inside regular text. it's difficult to get this absolutely right without parsing the HTML according to its grammar.

Comment: You don't need to have a cat before the grep. Just put f.html at the end of grep

Comment: And grep -o can fail due to a bug in some versions of grep.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you want to extract a URL from some HTML text, and not parse HTML (as one of the comments suggests).  Believe it or not, someone has already [done this](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/list_urls.sed).

OT: The [sed website](http://sed.sourceforge.net/) has a *lot* of good information and many interesting/crazy sed scripts.  You can even [play](http://aurelio.net/sed/sokoban/sokoban.sed) [Sokoban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) in sed!

Comment: This is the easiest and simplest answer. Just do e.g. `wget http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/list_urls.sed -O ~/bin/list_urls.sed && chmod +x ~/bin/list_urls.sed` to get the script, and then `wget http://www.example.com -O - | ~/bin/list_urls.sed > example.com.urls.txt` to get the urls in a text file!

Answer (score 4):

This is my first post, so I try to do my best explaining why I post this answer...

1. Since the first 7 most voted answers, 4 include GREP even when the
   post explicitly says "using sed or awk only".
2. Even when the post requires "No perl please", due to the previous
   point, and because use PERL regex inside grep.
3. and because this is the simplest way ( as far I know , and was
   required ) to do it in BASH.

So here come the simplest script from GNU grep 2.28:

```
grep -Po 'href="\K.*?(?=")'
```

About the `\K` switch , not info was founded in MAN and INFO pages, so I came [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573920/what-does-k-mean-in-this-regex) for the answer....
the `\K` switch get rid the previous chars ( and the key itself ).
Bear in mind following the advice from man pages:
"This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features."

Of course, you can modify the script to meet your tastes or needs, but I found it pretty straight for what was requested in the post , and also for many of us...

I hope folks you find it very useful.

thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

In bash, the following should work. Note that it doesn't use sed or awk, but uses `tr` and `grep`, both very standard and not perl ;-)

```
$ cat source_file.html | tr '"' '\n' | tr "'" '\n' | grep -e '^https://' -e '^http://' -e'^//' | sort | uniq
```

for example:

```
$ curl "https://www.cnn.com" | tr '"' '\n' | tr "'" '\n' | grep -e '^https://' -e '^http://' -e'^//' | sort | uniq
```

generates

```
//s3.amazonaws.com/cnn-sponsored-content
//twitter.com/cnn
https://us.cnn.com
https://www.cnn.com
https://www.cnn.com/2018/10/27/us/new-york-hudson-river-bodies-identified/index.html\
https://www.cnn.com/2018/11/01/tech/google-employee-walkout-andy-rubin/index.html\
https://www.cnn.com/election/2016/results/exit-polls\
https://www.cnn.com/profiles/frederik-pleitgen\
https://www.facebook.com/cnn
etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [kerkael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12495019/4355695):

```
grep "<a href=" sourcepage.html
  |sed "s/<a href/\\n<a href/g" 
  |sed 's/\"/\"><\/a>\n/2'
  |grep href
  |sort |uniq
# now adding some more
  |grep -v "<a href=\"#"
  |grep -v "<a href=\"../"
  |grep -v "<a href=\"http"
```

The first grep I added removes links to local bookmarks.

The second removes relative links to upper levels.

The third removes links that don't start with http.

Pick and choose which one of these you use as per your specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Go over with a first pass replacing the start of the urls (http) with a newline (`\n`http). Then you have guaranteed for yourself that your link starts at the beginning of the line and is the only URL on the line.
The rest should be easy, here is an example:

`sed "s/http/\nhttp/g" <(curl "http://www.cnn.com") | sed -n "s/\(^http[s]*:[a-Z0-9/.=?_-]*\)\(.*\)/\1/p"`

`alias lsurls='_(){ sed "s/http/\nhttp/g" "${1}" | sed -n "s/\(^http[s]*:[a-Z0-9/.=?_-]*\)\(.*\)/\1/p"; }; _'`

Answer (score 1):

Eschewing the `awk`/`sed` requirement:

1. `urlextract` is made just for such a task ([documentation](https://urlextract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)).
2. `urlview` is an interactive CLI solution ([github repo](https://github.com/sigpipe/urlview)).

Comment: [urlextract](https://github.com/lipoja/URLExtract/) worked fantastic — I was able to only extract around 30% of the desired URLs (exactly 100 in total) with lynx and grep. lynx gives the `Bad HTML!` error for the page (or a local HTML file in this case.'

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
curl --silent -u "<username>:<password>" http://<NAGIOS_HOST/nagios/cgi-bin/status.cgi|grep 'extinfo.cgi?type=1&host='|grep "status"|awk -F'</A>' '{print $1}'|awk -F"'>" '{print $3"\t"$1}'|sed 's/<\/a>&nbsp;<\/td>//g'| column -c2 -t|awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I tried it for better view, create shell file and give link as parameter, it will create temp2.txt file.

```
a=$1

lynx -listonly -dump "$a" > temp

awk 'FNR > 2 {print$2}' temp > temp2.txt

rm temp

>sh test.sh http://link.com
```

Comment: I strongly suggest to use a pipeline instead of temporary files: 

lynx -listonly -dump "$url" | awk 'FNR > 2 {print$2}'

Answer (score 0):

I scrape websites using Bash exclusively to verify the http status of client links and report back to them on errors found. I've found awk and sed to be the fastest and easiest to understand. Props to the OP.

```
curl -Lk https://example.com/ | sed -r 's~(href="|src=")([^"]+).*~\n\1\2~g' | awk '/^(href|src)/,//'
```

Because sed works on a single line, this will ensure that all urls are formatted properly on a new line, including any relative urls.  The first sed finds all href and src attributes and puts each on a new line while simultaneously removing the rest of the line, inlcuding the closing double qoute (") at the end of the link.

Notice I'm using a tilde (~) in sed as the defining separator for substitution. This is preferred over a forward slash (/). The forward slash can confuse the sed substitution when working with html.

The awk finds any line that begins with href or src and outputs it.

Once the content is properly formatted, awk or sed can be used to collect any subset of these links.  For example, you may not want base64 images, instead you want all the other images.  Our new code would look like:

```
curl -Lk https://example.com/ | sed -r 's~(href="|src=")([^"]+).*~\n\1\2~g' | awk '/^(href|src)/,//' | awk '/^src="[^d]/,//'
```

Once the subset is extracted, just remove the href=" or src="

```
sed -r 's~(href="|src=")~~g'
```

This method is extremely fast and I use these in Bash functions to format the results across thousands of scraped pages for clients that want someone to review their entire site in one scrape.

Answer (score 0):

Lynx did the job for me,
lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers bookmarks_10_10_23.html

but unlike the other response this doesn't display the numbers and you can feed the resulting URLs to another process for example:

```
 lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers bookmarks_10_10_23.html | xargs -L1 -i{} wayback_machine_downloader -e "{}"
```

what the options mean:

```
-dump  dumps  the  formatted  output  of  the  default document or those specified on the command line to
       standard output.  Unlike interactive mode, all documents are processed.  This can be used  in  the
       following way:

       lynx -dump http://www.subir.com/lynx.html
-listonly
       for -dump, show only the list of links.
-nonumbers
       disable link- and field-numbering.  This overrides -number_fields and -number_links.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ curl -ks <url> | awk -F'"' -v RS='[ >]' '/^href=/ && NF>2{print $2}'
```

Example:

```
$ curl -ks https://stackoverflow.com|awk -F'"' -v RS='[ >]' '/^href=/ && NF>2{print $2}'|sort -u | head -20
#
/
/collectives
/feeds
/help
/opensearch.xml
/questions
/tags
/teams/integrations/github
/teams/integrations/jira
/teams/integrations/microsoft-teams
/teams/integrations/okta
/teams/integrations/slack
/users
/users/signup?ssrc=product_home
https://ai.stackexchange.com
https://api.stackexchange.com/
https://apple.stackexchange.com
https://askubuntu.com/
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/Channels/channels.css?v=a4d77abedec3
```