# Manipulating strings in bash

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I have a file that contains a page of google which I got after a search. I used

```
w3m -no-cookie $search > google
```

to make the page

after that I need to get all the sites contained in that page, so basically all the strings that start with "www" and end with "/"

I tried :

```
grep -Fw "www" google | awk -F "/" '{ print $1";" }'
```

but it gives me everything that is on the line before www

how do I remove that?

should I use sed?

thanks!

Comment: Note that `w3m` does not give you the full url, and the string `www` will not necessarily find all urls.  You also don't know in what way google's search output may change over time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881237/easiest-way-to-extract-the-urls-from-an-html-page-using-sed-or-awk-only suggests the use of `lynx -dump -listonly`. Works for me.

Comment: This question isn't really about string manipulation in bash, it's more about string manipulation using gnu coreutils

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that all sites start with `www` is a bit weird, but here it is:

Your problem is that grep will return the whole line. With `-o` it will only return the matched part:

```
grep -wo "www.*" google | awk -F "/" '{ print $1";" }'
```

or simply:

```
grep -wo "www[^/]*" google
```