# Using sed in batchfile to get string between two other strings

Tags: batch-file, sed

I have an file with this html code inside:

```
 <p class="center-block"><img alt="ourpicture" class="picture" src="http://mypage.com/ourpicture123" /></p>
```

Now I would like to get just the source like http://mypage.com/ourpicture123.
How can I handle this problem with sed? It would be great if I can look for 'src="' before and '"' after.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to extract the urls from an html page using sed or awk only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881237/easiest-way-to-extract-the-urls-from-an-html-page-using-sed-or-awk-only)

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\bsrc="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' file
http://mypage.com/ourpicture123
```

Through grep,

```
grep -oP '\bsrc="\K[^"]*(?=")' file
```

The above sed command won't work if a line contains more than one `src` attribute present on a line. `\K` in the above grep command would discard the previously matched `src="` characters from printing at the final.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. When I use your command I get an error. Now sure if i translate it correct but something like this : ... Unknown command: `'''

Comment: ´ sed: -e Ausdruck #1, Zeichen 1: Unbekannter Befehl: `'' ´

Answer (score 0):

Here is an  `awk` version:

```
awk -F'src="' '{split($2,a,"\"");print a[1]}' file
http://mypage.com/ourpicture123
```

Or like this:

```
awk -F'src="' '{sub(/".*$/,"",$2);print $2}' file
http://mypage.com/ourpicture123
```

---

If you have several lines, and only needs line with `src=` do:

```
awk -F'src="' 'NF>1{split($2,a,"\"");print a[1]}' file
http://mypage.com/ourpicture123
```