# How can I execute this grep command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I was trying to match this pattern in regex 101

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google.com</a>
<A target="_blank" href='http://example.com/files.html'>An Example</A>
<a id="link23" HREF = "file23.html" target="_TOP">File #23</a>
<a href="images/mypic.png">See my picture!</a>
<a href="mailto:joelross@uw.edu">Email Joel</a>
```

and I made this regex- <[aA].*\s(HREF|href)\s?=\s?('|").*('|")>.*</[aA]>

now when I am trying to use the grep command via my command line,it throws me an error.

```
./mdlinks.sh: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./mdlinks.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here is the source file

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
CONTENT=$(curl $1)
echo "$CONTENT" | grep -E -o '<[aA].*\s(HREF|href)\s?=\s?('|").*('|")>.*<\/[aA]>' >> mdlinks.txt
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881237/easiest-way-to-extract-the-urls-from-an-html-page-using-sed-or-awk-only

Comment: use xmllint with an xpath query: http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes in the regex, and also your shebang has an extra space (although that's just style):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CONTENT=$(curl $1)
echo "$CONTENT" | grep -E -o '<[aA].*\s(HREF|href)\s?=\s?('\''|").*('\''|")>.*<\/[aA]>' >> mdlinks.txt
```

It might be worth using double quotes for the regex, rather than single quotes. You'll still have to escape the double quotes inside the expression, but escaping double quotes is a little cleaner:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CONTENT=$(curl $1)
echo "$CONTENT" | grep -E -o "<[aA].*\s(HREF|href)\s?=\s?('|\").*('|\")>.*<\/[aA]>" >> mdlinks.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. But I still am facing problems, the mdlinks file is just matching 1 anchor tag and not all the anchor tags present in the file

Comment: That's a problem with your regex. Try using non-greedy matches (`*?`) instead of greedy matches (`*`, which is the default behavior).