# Using wget to recursively fetch .txt files in .php file, but filters break the command

Tags: wget

I am looking to download all `quality_variant_[accession_name].txt` files from the [Salk Arabidopsis 1001 Genomes site](http://signal.salk.edu/atg1001/download.php) using `wget` in Bash shell.

- Main page with list of accessions: http://signal.salk.edu/atg1001/download.php
- Each accession links to a page (e.g., http://signal.salk.edu/atg1001/data/Salk/accession.php?id=Aa_0 where Aa_0 is the accession ID) containing three more links: unsequenced_[accession], quality_variant_[accession], and quality_variant_filtered_[accession]
- I am only interested in the quality_variant_[accession] link (not quality_variant_filtered_[accession] link), which takes you to to a `.txt` file with sequence data (e.g., http://signal.salk.edu/atg1001/data/Salk/quality_variant_Aa_0.txt)

Running the command below, the files of interest are eventually outputted (but not downloaded because of the --spider argument), demonstrating that `wget` can move through the page's hyperlinks to the files I want.

```
wget --spider --recursive "http://signal.salk.edu/atg1001/download.php
```

I have not let the command run long enough to determine whether the files of interest are downloaded, but the command below does begin to download the site recursively.

```
# Arguments in brackets do not impact the performance of the command
wget -r [-e robots=off] [-m] [-np] [-nd] "http://signal.salk.edu/atg1001/download.php"
```

However, whenever I try to apply filters to pull out the `.txt` files of interest, whether with `--accept-regex`, `--accept`, or many other variants, I cannot get past the initial `.php` file.

```
# This and variants thereof do not work
wget -r -A "quality_variant_*.txt" "http://signal.salk.edu/atg1001/download.php"

# Returns: 
# Saving to: ‘signal.salk.edu/atg1001/download.php.tmp’
# Removing signal.salk.edu/atg1001/download.php.tmp since it should be rejected.
```

I could make a list of the accession names and loop through those names modifying the URL in the wget command, but I was hoping for a dynamic one-liner that could extract all files of interest even if accession IDs are added over time.

Thank you!

---

Note: the data files of interest are contained in the directory `http://signal.salk.edu/atg1001/data/Salk/`, which is also home to a `.php` or static HTML page that is displayed when that URL is visited. This URL cannot be used in the wget command because, although the data files of interest are contained here server side, the HTML page contains no reference to these files but rather links to a different set of `.txt` files that I don't want.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be better off pulling a list of the URLs in question, and then passing those to wget?

Comment: parsing directly the links in the page with regexp is maybe an option : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881237/easiest-way-to-extract-the-urls-from-an-html-page-using-sed-or-awk-only